# Qualified import in Python

Tags: python-import, qualified-name

I am looking for a way to import certain methods from a module in a *qualified* manner; for instance (pseudo-code),

```
from math import sqrt as math.sqrt
# ...
SQRT2 = math.sqrt(2)
```

Is this possible?

This is useful for managing namespaces, in order not to pollute the global namespace. Futhermore, this scheme clearly indicates the source of a method/class in any part of the code.
I can also use an `import math`, but then the actual required methods (eg., `sqrt`) will be implicit.

Comment: What reason were you envisioning for a reader of your code to need know, at the top of the file, which methods belonging to an imported module would later be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) function with the `fromlist` parameter instead:

```
math = __import__('math', fromlist=['sqrt'])
SQRT2 = math.sqrt(2)
```

Comment: Sadly, there seems to be no clean solution in Python, similar to Haskell's `import qualified`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what problem do you see with using `import math` and then `math.sqrt`?

Do you want to name the namespace differently? Then do something like below:

```
import math as pymath
# ...
SQRT2 = pymath.sqrt(2)
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my OP, the slight problem with `import math` is that the actually-required methods (eg., `sqrt`) are absent from the `import` statement. One may add them via a comment, though.